# NLP multi-class classifier loss can’t go down

Tags: python, nlp, pytorch, multilabel-classification

I'm building a classifier for a QA bot, and  have **a dataset for 8k questions, and 149 different Answers.**

I got some problems when training my model; the "loss" won't go down as I expected so I am asking for your help...

#### Here is my method:

I use word2vec to get a word's vector, then use a GRU-based network to get the vector of sentence The w2v model has been trained with wiki data, and works well on another of my NLP projects. The GRU code is from my senior, I think it works well, too.

```
# Part of the code for getting sentence vector
input_size = 400 
hidden_dim = 400  
num_layers = 1
gru = nn.GRU(input_size, hidden_dim,num_layers,batch_first = True)

h0 = torch.rand(num_layers, 7187, hidden_dim) # (num_layers, batch, hidden_dim) 
# shape of input [dataset_len,max_sentence_len,input_feature]
inputSet = torch.tensor(x_train,dtype = torch.float)
sentenceVecs, hidden = gru(inputSet,h0)
sentenceVecs = sentenceVecs[:,-1, :]
```

and here is my classifier model

```
from argparse import Namespace
args = Namespace(
    dataset_file = 'dataset/waimai_10k_tw.pkl',
    model_save_path='torchmodel/pytorch_bce.model',
    # Training hyper parameters
    batch_size = 100,
    learning_rate = 0.002,
    min_learning_rate = 0.002,
    num_epochs=200,
)

class JWP(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, 
                 n_feature, 
                 n_hidden,
                 n_hidden2,
                 n_hidden3,
                 n_output):

        super(JWP, self).__init__()
        self.hidden = nn.Linear(n_feature, n_hidden)
        self.hidden2 = nn.Linear(n_hidden, n_hidden2)
        self.hidden3 = nn.Linear(n_hidden2, n_hidden3)
        self.out = nn.Linear(n_hidden3, n_output)

    def forward(self, x, apply_softmax=False):
        x = F.relu(self.hidden(x).squeeze())
        x = F.relu(self.hidden2(x).squeeze())
        x = F.relu(self.hidden3(x).squeeze())
        # 
        if(apply_softmax):
            x = torch.softmax(self.out(x))
        else:
            x = self.out(x)

        return x
```

training code

```
lr = args.learning_rate
min_lr = args.min_learning_rate
def adjust_learning_rate(optimizer, epoch):
    global lr
    if epoch % 10 == 0 and epoch != 0:
        lr = lr * 0.65
        if(lr < min_lr):
            lr = min_lr
        for param_group in optimizer.param_groups:
            param_group['lr'] = lr

if __name__ == "__main__":
    EPOCH = args.num_epochs
    net = JWP(400,325,275,225,149)
#     net = JWP(400,250,149)
#     net = JWP(400,149)
    print(net)

    optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(net.parameters(), lr=lr)
    loss_func = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

    for t in range(EPOCH):
        adjust_learning_rate(optimizer,t)

        """
        Train phase
        """
        net.train() 
        TrainLoss = 0.0
        # Train batch
        for step,(batchData, batchTarget) in enumerate(trainDataLoader):
            optimizer.zero_grad() 
            out = net(batchData)
            loss = loss_func(out,batchTarget) 
            TrainLoss = TrainLoss + loss
            loss.backward() 
            optimizer.step() 
        TrainLoss = TrainLoss / (step+1) # epoch loss

        """
        Result
        """
        print(
            "epoch:",t+1 ,
            "train_loss:",round(TrainLoss.item(),3),
            "LR:",lr
        )
```

Is it that my model is too simple or do I simply use the wrong method?
The loss is always stuck at around 4.6 and I can't lower it any more...

```
epoch: 2898 train_loss: 4.643 LR: 0.002
epoch: 2899 train_loss: 4.643 LR: 0.002
epoch: 2900 train_loss: 4.643 LR: 0.002
epoch: 2901 train_loss: 4.643 LR: 0.002
```

Comment: The question is whether you see a decrease in the initial training/learning phase. Is the reported loss after your 2900 epochs significantly lower than in then beginning? Then your model likely converged (or more, you're underfitting, if you actually evaluate the training loss). In such a case, try decreasing the model's complexity by introducing less hidden nodes, or increasing the learning rate.

Answer (score 0):

came back ans myself:
there’s some “very long sentence” in my dataset, may make some “noise”, because of RNN(GRU) method hard to keep those info, after taking “very long sentence” away from my dataset, loss strat going down and acc was pertty